Flutter Auth0: Stuck at Waiting for connection from debug service on chrome
I want to use auth0 in the web while using flutter.
The docs from auth0 (https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/flutter/interactive) say to include this line of code in the index.html:
<script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/auth0-spa-js/2.0/auth0-spa-js.production.js" defer></script>

But if I include that and start in chrome I get this message while the chrome tab that opened up is all white:
Flutter: Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...

This a clean project with and no other changes happend to any settings files, only the index.html.
The body part of the index.html:
<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/auth0-spa-js/2.0/auth0-spa-js.production.js" defer></script>
  <script src="flutter_bootstrap.js" async></script>
</body>

I have no errors or logs available it only tells the message from above.
This error only happens if I start in debug mode. Release mode works sometimes.
Any ideas on how to fix this?
